# Get number of days for previous month

Tags: php, date

I'm using this code to get number of days in last month, but if the current month is January (01) it's going to use 00 month instead of 12.

```
$prev_month_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m')-1, date('Y'));
```

Searched Google for 20 minutes and could not find any reasonable and shorthand solution.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: so check if `date('m')` is `1`. if so, convert `1,xxxx` to `12,xxxx minus 1`

Comment: `date('m') - 1 ?: 12` would be my preferred answer, but there are dozens of ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 

echo date("t", mktime(0,0,0, date("n") - 1));

?>
```

Comment: Elegant and shorthandy!

Comment: it wouldn't work with the date of 2024-03-30

Answer (score 0):

The example provided by Dan is not correct.

You have to check the result of date("n") and correct for January return

And if this is part of a time function, which seems logical since you are looking for the previous number of days in a month. You will also have to compensate for the year shifting back. Otherwise you would shoot to December of the current year.

What works better is..

```
$NowYear = date("Y");
$NowMonth = date("n");

if ($NowMonth == 1) {
    $ThenMonth = 12;
    $ThenYear = $NowYear - 1;
}
else {
    $ThenMonth = $NowMonth - 1;
    $ThenYear = $NowYear;
}

$ThenNumberOfDays = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $ThenMonth, 1, $ThenYear));
```

$ThenNumberOfDays would have the correct number of days...